# Is there a way to edit a bounty description? Should there be?

Tags: feature-request, bounty

I just placed a bounty on an old [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112404/reliable-code-for-automatic-noindent-after-specific-environments) of mine. Silly me, I used backticks in a LaTeX way rather than a StackExchange way, so the formatting of the bounty description is messed up.

I don't believe there is a way to fix this. Of course, we don't want the bounty conditions to change midway through the week, but shouldn't there be a short period during which typos can be fixed? There is already a similar period during which a question can be edited without an "Edited" message appearing.

Comment: Related post on Meta.SO: [Add a grace period for bounty removal / reversal?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/111967/168244) However, they are considering a more general approach to bounties (including removal/reversal), which seem to avoid any interest similar to this specific request.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Could you share (a link to) a description of this more general approach?

Comment: The link in my comment discusses the general approach: Allow for a grace period of editing the bounty description before it is locked, but also allow the bounty issuer to possibly retract the bounty. The latter is more controversial and therefore gain(ed) more attention. The former is what you're after, and very much justifiable.

Comment: Ah, when you said "a more general approach", I thought you meant "more general than the post on Meta.SO". --- If I understand the proposal correctly, a bounty can only be retracted while it is still invisible to the outside world. So that particular feature seems not so much controversial as pointless.